# How can I use bearer token authentication for accessing report server where report is opening in different tab?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, authorization, asp.net-identity, bearer-token

**Problem Statement**

I'm working on a SPA in which a user can see/view different reports in pdf, text and html etc.
Since we are using authorization server and resource servers separately and each resource server has to request for user identity to the authorization server and then authorization server will provide a bearer token to access the resources.

now each request must have an authorization header with bearer token to access the resources.

In my case SPA is opening new tab to access different kind of reports with direct url ( It's a requirement) so in this case I can't set authorization header.

Is there any standardized way to handle this kind of situations?

I tried three options for handling this.

**#Token in url ( not a good practice)**

**#Javascript [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) (some browsers doesn't support)**

```
 var config = {
            responseType:'arraybuffer',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': $window.sessionStorage.token
            }
        };

        $http.get(url, config).then(function onSuccess(response) {

            var contentType = response.headers("content-type");
            var blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: contentType });
            var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            window.open(fileURL);
        });
```

**#Set cookies ( This is working but I'm looking for different solutions where only bearer token will be used for authorization)**

Here is my reporting controller code for getting report

```
[Authorize(User="CanView")]
    public ContentResult GetReport(string type, int id)
    {
        return new ContentResult() { Content = someByte, ContentType = "application/pdf" };
    }
```

Comment: Put token in a query string. :)